# Integrating maximum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $P$ be a probability measure, $0\le s<t<\infty$ real numbers and $Y$ be a random variable.

\begin{align}
&\int_{(s,t]}\int_{(s,t]} P(Y\ge \max\{u,v\})\  du\  dv\\
&=\int_{(s,t]}\int_{(s,v]} P(Y\ge v)\  du\  dv\ +\ \int_{(s,t]}\int_{(v,t]} P(Y\ge u)\  du\  dv\ \\
&=\int_{(s,t]}\int_{[u,t]} P(Y\ge v)\  dv\  du\ +\ \int_{(s,t]}\int_{(v,t]} P(Y\ge u)\  du\  dv\ \\
&=\int_{(s,t]}\int_{[u,t]} P(Y\ge v)\  dv\  du\ +\ \int_{(s,t]}\int_{[u,t]} P(Y\ge v)\  dv\  du\ - \int_{(s,t]}\int_{\{u\}} P(Y\ge v)\  dv\  du\\\
\end{align}

First equation is clear, but I do not understand the second and third. Can someone give me a hint on this one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second step, for the integral over $u$, the interval is split into two parts given by $(s, v]$ and $(v, t]$. Note that if $u \in (s, v]$ then $\max\{u,v\} = v$ and if $u \in (v, t]$ then $\max\{u,v\} = u$. Hence we can write $\displaystyle \int_{(s,t]} P(Y \geq \max\{u,v\}) \ du = \int_{(s,v]} P(Y \geq v) \ du +\int_{(v,t]} P(Y \geq u) \ du$. This should give you the second step.

The third step is just a change of order of integration which changes the limits in the first integral.

The fourth step is the change of variables, that is $u$ becomes $v$ and vice versa. Also notice that the interval of integration changed from $(v,t]$ to $[u,t] = \{ u \} \cup (u, t]$. That accounts for the last integral that is subtracted.

Comment: Ok, I see, the last step is really just renaming the variables. But I still not get what you name as third step. I see that I can pull out the value $P(Y\ge v)$, but how do I get the interval $[u,t]$?

Comment: In the second step, the region you are integrating over in the $u-v$ plane is a right-angled triangle with its three vertices at $(s,s), (s,t)$ and $(t,t)$ (written as $(u,v)$). If you integrate $u$ first then you get the given limits. However, if you wish to integrate $v$ first, then note that for every value of $u$, $v$ will range from $[u,t]$ in the above mentioned region. This should give you the limits for the changed order of integration. I suggest you draw the figure, and then follow this procedure. It would be easier to follow then.

Comment: Actually, this is just the usual technique, how to  change the order of integration. I forgot about that, but is of course something I've learned some time ago. :) Thanks for replying!

Comment: Yeah it is pretty common that's why I had just mentioned it in the answer without much detail. 
No problem :)